# Is it possible to apply drop shadow to only one segment of the png image?

Tags: css, dropshadow

We will refer to this image for rest of the question: https://images.app.goo.gl/7v6wQfheMw2vivSu5

My usecase here is I'm trying to show a random set of images inside a Photo frame element as in the above link.

The photo frame is a PNG, and I want to give shadow to only the right side of the frame. The shape of the frame may change.

I've tried using `drop-shadow` property of css, it does resolve a part of the problem by honouring the frame, but it applies the shadow to both the sides of the frame, and I just want it on the right side of the frame.

Can this be achieved completely by using CSS?

Comment: Why not simply use `box-shadow` ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Box shadow will add shadow to the image element, and not the image itself

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, Can you put up a code snippet illustrating the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

remove your `dropshadow` thing and add the following to your css code: `box-shadow: 10px 0 5px -2px #888;`

hope this helps, if not let me know